# SFMC PushSDK not reporting any opens

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I'm implementing the Mobile PushSDK in a native android app with Firebase, I've managed to make the app receive notifications from Marketing Cloud.

However, it's not reporting any opens. Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Have you enabled Analytics in sdk? 

http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-iOS/features/analytics.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have enabled analytics (correct link for Android docs http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/features/analytics.html) and you're still not seeing opens; have you customized notification handling in your application?  If so, did you wrap your `PendingIntent` such that the SDK can report analytics? See http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/notifications/customize-notifications.html#simplified-customization

Comment: You were right, I had customised notification handling. In my notification service (Android) I added this and it worked:
`if (PushMessageManager.isMarketingCloudPush(msg))
 MarketingCloudSdk.requestSdk(sdk -> sdk.getPushMessageManager().handleMessage(msg));`

Comment: You can also simply pass your `PendingIntent` and the NotificationMessage into our analytics helper: `NotificationManager.redirectIntentForAnalytics(context, pendingIntent, notificationMessage, true)`

Comment: Hi @Bill, what's the difference between the two? the last argument seems to imply the redirectIntentForAnalaytics also creates a status bar notification?